# Stable amplitude of amplified signal

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, analog, op-amp

Is there any circuit with opamp where can be (by arduino) set constant output amplitude which doesn't depend on input signals amplitude?

Comment: What signal? It sounds like you're asking for an AGC circuit with adjustable level.

Comment: NB: AGC = [Automatic Gain Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_gain_control)

Comment: Yes. AGC will help me in this project. Thank you both.

Comment: Just for grins I googled "digital control AGC" and got about 5 million hits. A lot more information is needed to properly answer your question. Please define the input and output signals, level, frequency, etc. Note the rate of change will have a large effect on the AGC filters and Arduino response (partially controlled by your software) will make or break the whole design. Include a proposed schematic, not a frizzy drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a word of advice about AGC in general.  There is almost always an issue of attack (how fast the AGC reacts to a sudden increase in signal) and release (how fast it reacts to a decrease).  In most AGC cases you will need to make compromises on these two settings to avoid poor behavior from the AGC... it's not a drop-in solution with pre-determined optimum settings for every purpose.  Depending on the program material, you can get obnoxious artifacts like breathing and pumping for speech and music.  ACG is much better at slow drifting things like signal fade.  I just want you know what you might be getting into...